# How can get view name in mvc 4 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm want to read a active View name and fill it to ViewName public Class

I make a Model Class where I'm fetching textBox data with

```
public string ViewName { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }       
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Comment { get; set; }
```

in layout I have written a code in form tag it was send text box value in rest of public string class's

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/SendMail" id="contactfrm" role="form">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            @Html.TextBox("Name", null, new { id = "name", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter name", title = "Please enter your name (at least 2 characters)" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            @Html.TextBox("Email", null, new { id = "email", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter name", title = "Please enter a valid email address)" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="comments">Comments</label>
                            @Html.TextArea("Comment", null, new { id = "comments", @class = "form-control", TextMode = "MultiLine", Columns = "3", Rows = "5", placeholder = "Enter your message…", title = "Please enter your message (at least 10 characters)" })
                        </div>
                        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="submit">Send Your Message</button>
                        <div class="result"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

what i want to do now I want to read active view name also for fill the ViewName public class which for post back it again with same view are active in layout. Have you guys any idea how can I read the viewName and fill it in Public Class? please let me know where in can add this in Form tag.

Thank You in advance

Comment: _Pubic Class_.. Come one man.. take your time and post the question.. No competition here.. Also why `jquery` has been tagged?

Comment: man I'm learning MVC that whats wrong to take some help from experts over there.

Comment: See I meant no offense.. I just wanted you to correct the way you are asking question.. You need to follow SO policies while asking question.. Keep your question minimal yet explanatory.. In your above question explain where you want to read the `ViewName`? in `controller`? if yes then in which `controller`? and you have created model but with your above `view` code you are not creating strongly typed view w.r.t to your model and if you read your sentence after you view code above then you will find lot of mistakes basically verbiage. Correct that if possible.. `Pubic` has a very bad meaning..

Comment: For this time I've edited your question.. Also.. We are happy to help you if you come up with more specific problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 possible ways to get View hame on Razor View.

First is `VirtualPath` property on View and you can get View Name From path:

```
@Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Server.MapPath(VirtualPath))
```

Second is `ViewContext` but that will work only if you use MVC conversations and call in your controller `return View()` without explicity passing View name.

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()
```

Comment: Hi teo van thank you for your suggesting I'm getting view like this   @{
                        var ViewName= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
                    }
I want to know how can I get the ViewName in get class I have masked where i will call a code for fill it under form tag

Answer (score 0):

if you use the `RazorView`
you can get the View path by the code following:

```
(this.ViewContext.View as RazorView).ViewPath
```

Comment: I want to send view name in get set class how can I send it?